# Violin recording of Johann Ernst Prinz playing Bach Violin Concerto in C Major? (BWV 984)

Tags: johann-sebastian-bach

I remember I encountered a violin rendition of BWV 984 on youtube, but the channel that uploaded it has gone down for copyright reasons.

Does anyone know where I could find this recording?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anyone is interested, the recording was by Freiburg Musica Poetica Ensemble, and the album is: Bach, J.S.: Mein Herze Schwimmt!

Comment: [Link to record](https://www.chandos.net/products/catalogue/HA%208408)